How can i fetch specific data from API
I'm making a blog site, and I have an API that has 100 article (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts),
First I've fetched 10 articles by using this code:
async function getData(url){
    let data = await fetch(`${url}/?_limit=10`)
    let posts = data.json();
    // Then map it to show posts up
}

getData("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")

Now when I click the Watch More button I want to fetch articles from 11 - 20;
how can I do that?

it depends on your api.

You need to make your code more dynamic for that:
async function getData(url, start, limit){
    let data = await fetch(`${url}/?_start=${start}&_limit=${limit}`)
    let posts =  data.json();
}

To call this function, you need to use parameters accordingly.
await getData("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", 0, 10)

